# Uploading files with commas and other special characters to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having hard time displaying files with special characters uploaded to Wordpress. My functions works fine until I try to upload file like john,smith.jpg. Wordpress uploads all the files so this is not issue. The problem is the url that is returned from Wordpress isn't interpreted as valid source file url for browsers.

For example when I upload file marcia,dave_03.jpg the returned URL is http://example.com/uploads/2015/03/Dove,Marcia_03.jpg

And browser claims that this resource doesn't exist. How should I proceed?
Janusz

```
if (in_array($_FILES['profile_photo']['type'], $types)) :
        // Your file handing script here
        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
        $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['profile_photo'], $upload_overrides );
        if ( $movefile ) {
            //echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";

                //upload attachment
                $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                //it must be absolute path to work
                $file =  $upload_dir['path'] ."/".$_FILES["profile_photo"]["name"];

                $guid = $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $_FILES["profile_photo"]["name"]);
                $attachment = array(
                    'guid'           =>$guid , 
                    'post_mime_type' => $_FILES["profile_photo"]["type"] ,
                    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $_FILES["profile_photo"]["name"]  ) ),
                    'post_content'   => '',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
                );
            // Insert the attachment.
            $photo_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment,$file);
            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $photo_id); 

            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $photo_id, $file);
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $photo_id, $attach_data );

            User:: setUserPhoto($current_user_id, $photo_id);
        } else {
            echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }   
    else:
    // Error, filetype not supported
        $messages[] = "This file type is not supported";
    endif;
```

Comment: Commas are [reserved characters in URLs](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) and should be encoded. Try visiting `http://example.com/uploads/2015/03/Dove%2CMarcia_03.jpg` and see if that works.

Comment: No. It doesn't. I am getting a 404 error.